# How to dynamically add an input value in a dataframe that takes data from an API in Json format

Tags: python, dataframe

This is a bit of a complex task where 99% of the work is done but there is just a tiny bit that escapes me still!

```
import os
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statistics
import datetime
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = {'name': ['toronto68', 'm-3', 'torchpogi']}  
# Create DataFrame  
accounttest = pd.DataFrame(data)  
print(accounttest)

def loadaccountcollection(inputpar):
    url = "https://game-api.splinterlands.com/cards/collection/{account}"
    session = requests.Session()

    payload = {}
    headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer (STRING)',
      '(STRING)': '(STRING)'
    }
    my_list = []

    #for account in testact:
    for account in inputpar["name"]:
        #    response = requests.get(url.format(account=account) , headers="", data = payload)
        r = session.get(url.format(account=account))
        print(r)
        x = r.json()
        #Potentially need something here that create a new column "account" based on account passed
        my_list.append(x)
    #df = pd.DataFrame(my_list) 
    return my_list

df = loadaccountcollection(accounttest)
print(df)
```

With this code i have 3 account names in a dataframe and a function where I can pass as parameters those 3 account names and have a dynamic query to an API using that parameter.
The result of the query for each account is a quite complex nested JSON structure.

What i want to achieve is create one dataframe where the content of the JSON is normalised in a table and i have an additional column called "account" that tells me from which account the rows come from. Only three possible values 'toronto68' or 'm-3' or 'torchpogi'

What I can do something like this

```
df2 = pd.json_normalize(df,"cards")
```

At the time I am writing it has 268 rows (this can change depending on when the code is executed as the API response changes over time) but i do not know which rows are for account 'toronto68' or 'm-3' or 'torchpogi'

I am sure is much easier but i literally spent 2+ hours trying to solve this and also going to crazy solutions like during the loop convert in a dataframe, add the column and then recreate the json but in the end it didnt work out :(

Answer (score 0):

I just used for loops to iterate through the json response (x). I created a new function. To be able to see how I did this I just start with something like this:

```
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

Then I try:

```
for i in x:
    for j in i:
        print(j)
```

Eventually I parse out just the "cards" value and then I build the data frame into a list that pd.concat() can easy concatenate.

This might not be the best method, but with these abstract data responses it is sometimes the only way.

Final code:

```
import os
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statistics
import datetime
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = {'name': ['toronto68', 'm-3', 'torchpogi']}
accounttest = pd.DataFrame(data)

def loadaccountcollection(inputpar):
    url = "https://game-api.splinterlands.com/cards/collection/{account}"
    session = requests.Session()

    payload = {}
    headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer (STRING)',
      '(STRING)': '(STRING)'
    }
    my_list = []
    for account in inputpar["name"]:
        #    response = requests.get(url.format(account=account) , headers="", data = payload)
        r = session.get(url.format(account=account))
        x = r.json()
        #Added the Pandas creation dataframe here
        xx = build_df(x, account)
        my_list.append(xx)
    return my_list


def build_df(list_, account_name):
    dfs = []
    for j in list_:
        if j == 'cards':
            for k in i[j]:
                dfs.append(pd.DataFrame( pd.Series(k)).T  )
                        
    dff = pd.concat(dfs)
    dff.index = range(len(dff))
    dff['NAME'] = account_name
                        
    return dff
    
    
df2 = pd.concat(loadaccountcollection(accounttest))
df2
```

Comment: Mmm i am a bit lost on what you are trying to do here with this parsing and recreating of the lists.
I also got an error saying that the i is not defined

Comment: Sorry for delay i accidently left the variable i and it should have been list_ . It is updated now.